# 2 Bit Counter using JK Flip Flop in Verilog

Tags: counter, verilog, flip-flop

I'm writing verilog code of 2 Bit Counter using JK Flip Flop that counts 0-3 and back to 0. I'm using Xilinx EDA. However I'm keep getting one error and I don't know what it means? The line numbers doesn't show up here, but error is located at "`always @(posedge clk)`".

> ERROR:HDLCompiler:1401 - "C:\Users\Eduardo\Documents\SFSU\Fall 2014\Engr 378\Lab 3\TwoBitCounter\twobitcounter.v" Line 30: Signal q in unit jkff is connected to following multiple drivers:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module twobitcounter( q_out, qbar_out, j,k, clk, reset);
    input [1:0] j; input [1:0] k; input clk; input reset;
    output [1:0] q_out;
    output [1:0] qbar_out;
    wire [1:0] q_out;
    wire [1:0] qbar_out;
    wire clk;

    assign qbar_out[0] = ~q_out[0];
    assign j[0] = 1;
    assign k[0] = 1;
    assign j[1] = q_out[0];
    assign k[1] = q_out[0]; 

    jkff M1(q_out[0], qbar_out[0], j[0], k[0], clk, reset);
    jkff M2(q_out[1], qbar_out[1], j[1], k[1], qbar_out[0]);

endmodule

module jkff(output q_out, output qbar_out,
  input j, input k, input clk, input reset);

    reg q;
    assign q_out = q;
    assign qbar_out = ~q;

    initial begin 
        q = 1'b0;
        end
    always @(posedge clk)
        begin
        case({j,k})
        {1'b0, 1'b0}: begin
            q = q;
            end
        {1'b0, 1'b1}: begin
            q = 1'b0;
            end
        {1'b1, 1'b0}: begin
            q = 1'b1;
            end
        {1'b1, 1'b1}: begin
            q = ~q;
            end
        endcase
        end

    always @(posedge reset)
        begin
        q = 1'b0;
        end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is `q` is being set in two `always` blocks, which is not allowed in synthesis. Merge the two always blocks. Also, `q` is a flop, so it should be assigned using non-blocking assignment (`<=`), not blocking assignment (`=`).

```
always @(posedge clk or posedge reset)
begin
  if (reset == 1'b1) begin
    q <= 1'b0;
  end
  else begin
    case({j,k})
    {1'b0, 1'b0}: begin
        q <= q;
        end
    {1'b0, 1'b1}: begin
        q <= 1'b0;
        end
    {1'b1, 1'b0}: begin
        q <= 1'b1;
        end
    {1'b1, 1'b1}: begin
        q <= ~q;
        end
    endcase
  end
end
```

You should almost never use `initial` blocks in synthesizable code. Most FPGAs allow it for initialization. ASICs designs however do not support it. For both cases, if there is an asynchronous reset/set then it initial block shouldn't be used.

Comment: I tried your advise, but it gave me same error for module twobitcounter. I get an error at "assign qbar_out[0] = ~q_out[0];" It states that qbar_out[0] is connected to following multiple drivers

Comment: `q_out[0]` and `qbar_out[0]` are both outputs of M1. That makes it dual driver which is illegal. Comment out `assign qbar_out[0] = ~q_out[0];`. Your also missing a port connection on M2

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that you are assigning q in different blocks.  This creates an error.  You are assigning q in both your `initial` block and your `always` block.

You should never use `initial` blocks in synthesizable code.

Comment: **Almost never use initial blocks (most synthesis tools for FPGAs allo initial blocks in certain cases, like initializing memory elements). Also, q is assigned in the @(posedge reset) block as well.